# convert dtype object with tuples into np.array

Tags: python

I have a dtype object `e`:

```
>>> e

dtype([('cards', 'O'), ('store', 'O'), ('march', 'O'),
     ('fam', 'O'), ('cup', 'O'), ('sex', 'O'), ('educ', 'O'),  
     ('age', 'O'), ('handedness', 'O')])
```

I want to make this into an array of strings:

```
np.array(['cards','store','march','fam','cup','sex','educ','age','handedness'])
```

Is there a way to convert this object into an array as shown?

I have tried the suggestions here:

[How to convert a Numpy 2D array with object dtype to a regular 2D array of floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459017/how-to-convert-a-numpy-2d-array-with-object-dtype-to-a-regular-2d-array-of-float)

but I get the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-160-dc37d6f17f2f> in <module>()
----> 1 np.array(list(e[:, 1]), dtype=str)

ValueError: Field key must be an integer, string, or unicode.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
np.array(e.names)
```

The [`names`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.names.html#numpy.dtype.names) attribute of a dtype object is a tuple of its field names, or `None` if it doesn't have fields.