# TypeError: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.object_

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

How to convert a numpy array of `dtype=object` to torch `Tensor`?

```
array([
   array([0.5, 1.0, 2.0], dtype=float16),
   array([4.0, 6.0, 8.0], dtype=float16)
], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Can you show us a small example how you try to convert the numpy array to the torch tensor? So that we can run it by ourselves?

Comment: I'm not surprised that `pytorch` has problems creating a `tensor` from an object dtype array.  That's an array of arrays - arrays which are stored elsewhere in memory.  But it may work with `data.tolist()`, a list of arrays.  Or join them into a 2d array with `np.stack(data)`.  This will only work where the component arrays have the same shape (as appears to be the case here).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is difficult to answer properly since you do not show us how you try to do it. From your error message I can see that you try to convert a numpy array containing objects to a torch tensor. This does not work, you will need a numeric data type:

```
import torch
import numpy as np

# Your test array without 'dtype=object'
a = np.array([
    np.array([0.5, 1.0, 2.0], dtype=np.float16),
    np.array([4.0, 6.0, 8.0], dtype=np.float16),
])

b = torch.from_numpy(a)

print(a.dtype) # This should not be 'object'
print(b)
```

**Output**

```
float16
tensor([[0.5000, 1.0000, 2.0000],
        [4.0000, 6.0000, 8.0000]], dtype=torch.float16)
```

Comment: Your `a` is a tuple.  It shouldn't have a `dtype`.

Comment: No, it is not a tuple. I added some indentation so one can see it more clearly.

Answer (score 10):

Just adding to what was written above:

First you should make sure your array dtype isn't a 'O' (Object).

You do that by: ([credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459017/how-to-convert-a-numpy-2d-array-with-object-dtype-to-a-regular-2d-array-of-float))

```
a=np.vstack(a).astype(np.float)
```

Then you can use:

```
b = torch.from_numpy(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `.astype()` to transform the type of your data.
i use this successfully. you can try