# Converting numpy arrays to pytorch format

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I am trying to convert data from `numpy` to `pytorch`. Code below.

`inputs = torch.from_numpy(inputs_array),float()`

But it gives me the following error

> TypeError: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.object_. The only
> supported types are: float64, float32, float16, complex64, complex128,
> int64, int32, int16, int8, uint8, and bool.

kindly help in this regard

Comment: `pytorch` does not support tensors of type `object`. A solution depends on *inputs_array*, which is not provided in the example code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.object\_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55724123/typeerror-cant-convert-np-ndarray-of-type-numpy-object)

Answer (score 0):

The content of `inputs_array` has a wrong data format.

Just make sure that `inputs_array` is a numpy array with `inputs_array.dtype` in `[float64, float32, float16, complex64, complex128, int64, int32, int16, int8, uint8, bool]`.

You can provide `inputs_array` content for further help.